# How To Add Class To Parent Div which contains image of certain size?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to add a class to the parent div depending on particular size of the image inside the parent div.

But this jquery code doesn't works when i add more div element in the parent container

code looks something like this

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src='http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Go-gvkEm4Rw/UszzNls6EYI/AAAAAAAAEfQ/qds_K1jXgLE/s1600/doctype-hi-res1-960x305.jpg'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want a jquery code which can add class to the main parent div depending on the size of image of certain width.

Comment: What do you mean by size

Comment: And what is the parent div, the div containing the image or one of all the other div's you've added ?

Comment: Please show the jquery code you have tried

Answer (score 5):

Use the image load handler... like

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('img').load(function () {
        //check the desired size here
        if (this.width > 48) {
            $(this).parents(':eq(2)').addClass('special')
        }
    }).filter(function () {
        return this.complete
    }).trigger('load')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z9N7K/)

Comment: wow! so smart to understand.

Comment: @C-link just guessed... hopefully correctly

Comment: Wow, that really looks cool. Could you please elaborate on several things like: 1. Why you need to filter? 2. Why you have to trigger the load handler (?) again on the loaded images? Thank you!

Comment: @dollarvar when we are registering the handler in a dom ready handler there are chances that the image might have already loaded(before the handler is registered - one reason for it could be the image is already cached) so the `load` event will not get triggered for already loaded elements

Comment: @dollarvar so after registering the handler we use filter to check whether any of the images are already loaded if so then manually trigger the load event for them

Answer (score 0):

```
$(img).parent().addClass('classname');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I've achieved it already it's similar like you jQuery function only difference is I'm using height instead of width of the image
Here's the jQuery function which I'm using

`

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('img';).each(function() {
    var div = $(this);
    var $par = $(this).closest('div');
    if(this.height >= 100) {
        $par.addClass('';);
    } else {
        $par.addClass('landscape');
    }
})
});
```

`