# Switching images periodically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, settimeout

I'm trying to make a background which changes it's image every few seconds. I needed to get a fade in, fade out effect, which is why I used an `<img>`.

The images fade in for 2 seconds and after 8 seconds, it fades out for another 2 seconds. Then another image gets selected and everything repeats.

It works, but it skips a cycle every once and a while (randomly). The image fades out, and nothing happens for 8 seconds. Then a new image appears. It's happening quite a lot, which is why I need to get it fixed. I've got this issue on Chrome and Opera. My friend tested it on Firefox and said he didn't get the issue and when he tested it on Internet Explorer (I don't know which version, but it's on Windows 8.1) and the issue appeared, but it remained blank. No new image appeared when the error occured.

I'm really scratching my head on this one, I can't get it fixed.

I'm using this jQuery code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var aImages = new Array();
  var iPrev = 0;
  var iRnd = 0;

  aImages[0] = "images/background01.jpg";
  aImages[1] = "images/background02.jpg";
  aImages[2] = "images/background03.jpg";
  aImages[3] = "images/background04.jpg";
  aImages[4] = "images/background05.jpg";

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("img#bg").load(function() {
      $("img#bg").fadeTo(2000, 1);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("img#bg").fadeOut(2000);
        setTimeout(LoadImages, 2000);
      }, 8000);
    });

    setTimeout(LoadImages, 200);
  });

  function LoadImages() {
    while(iPrev == iRnd) {
      iRnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*aImages.length);
    }
    $("img#bg").attr("src", aImages[iRnd]);
    iPrev = iRnd;
  }
</script>
```

I don't think the css has some part in this, but here it is:

```
img#bg {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And for the sake of keeping it simple, here is the html code:

```
<body>
  <img id="bg">
</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not randomly selecting the same image? At a quick glance at your code I don't see anything to stop that from happening and it looks like it might cause the issue you're seeing.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR There is something to stop that happening: `while(iPrev == iRnd)`. The thing I would suggest checking is that all 5 urls are valid and return images.

Comment: Derp. Missed that entirely, my bad.

Comment: Think there is a race condition between the two `setTimeout(LoadImages, ...)` and faded/unfaded image.

Comment: You have another problem. If the image lives in the cache. ["Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache"](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). Look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20993478/2672018!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a race condition going on between the `fadeOut` and the `setTimeout` right after it. It may be that `LoadImages` runs a split second before the `fadeOut` finishes, and this somehow causes the `load` event to not fire.

When I try your code, I see the picture alternate on for 10 seconds, blank for 10 seconds, consistently.

`fadeOut()` has a `complete` parameter, so there's no need to use a `setTimeout` to "predict" when the `fadeOut` is going to finish. Just use the `complete` parameter.

In other words, replace this:

```
$("img#bg").fadeOut(2000);
setTimeout(LoadImages, 2000);
```

with this:

```
$("img#bg").fadeOut(2000, LoadImages);
```

When I use this, I don't get the on/off alternation like I do with your original code.

Comment: Hey JL, stupid question, but how does the repeat occur here, btw?

Comment: I'll test this on the other browsers as well, in Chrome it seems to be working as I want it to now. :)

Comment: Ah, by the `load` event. Dang. You said it. ;)